# Blank html page rendering instead of React website render

Tags: html, reactjs

i am unable to render my React website after deploying and publishing code via github and/or netlify. It gives me a blank page instead of rendering my website. I have referred to existing answers and tried many possible solutions but it still doesn't work any help will be highly appreciated.

I am trying to access my website via index.html in root folder, however, instead of url accessing my main.jsx through index.html, it is simply rendering my index.html in root.

**The website is published here:**
https://mustafafarooqusman.github.io/Murtazaportfolio-main/ (showing a blank page)

**My repository is placed here:**
https://github.com/MustafaFarooqUsman/Murtazaportfolio-main

**My index.html in root is as followed:**

```
`> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en">
>   <head>
>     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
>     <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./logo.svg" />
>     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
>     <title>Murtaza | 3D Portfolio</title>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <div id="root"></div>
>     <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
>   </body>
> </html>`
```

**My main.jsx in src folder is as followed:**

```
`> import React from "react";
> import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
> 
> import App from "./App";
> import "./index.css";
> 
> ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
>   <React.StrictMode>
>     <App />
>   </React.StrictMode>
> );`
```

**My app.jsx is as followed:**

```
`> import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
> 
> import {
> About,
> Contact,
> Experience,
> Feedbacks,
> Hero,
> Navbar,
> Tech,
> Works,
> StarsCanvas,
> from "./components";
> 
> const App = () => {
> return (
>     <BrowserRouter>
>       <div className="relative z-0 bg-primary">
>         <div className="bg-hero-pattern bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-center">
>           <Navbar />
>           <Hero />
>         </div>
>         <About />
>         <Experience />
>         <Tech />
>         <Works />
>         <Feedbacks />
>         <div className="relative z-0">
>           <Contact />
>           <StarsCanvas />
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </BrowserRouter>
>   );
> };
> 
> export default App;`
```

**My package.json in root folder is as followed:**

```
`> {
>   "name": "3dfolio",
>   "private": true,
>   "version": "0.0.0",
>   "type": "module",
>   "scripts": {
>     "dev": "vite",
>     "build": "vite build",
>     "preview": "vite preview"
>   },
>   "dependencies": {
>     "@emailjs/browser": "^3.10.0",
>     "@react-three/drei": "^9.56.24",
>     "@react-three/fiber": "^8.11.1",
>     "framer-motion": "^9.0.7",
>     "maath": "^0.5.2",
>     "react": "^18.2.0",
>     "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
>     "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
>     "react-tilt": "^0.1.4",
>     "react-vertical-timeline-component": "^3.6.0",
>     "three": "^0.149.0"
>   },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
>     "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
>     "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
>     "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
>     "postcss": "^8.4.21",
>     "tailwindcss": "^3.2.6",
>     "vite": "^4.1.0"
>   }
> }`
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This usually happens when you have an unhandled error. What do you see in the console output in dev tools on the browser?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()          main.jsx:1

Comment: Did you run `npm run build`? The compiled code will be in the newly created `dist` folder. That’s what you have to upload.

Comment: yes, npm run build then npm run dev, its working correctly on localhost, not after deployment